# Android Navcontroller hardware back button crash

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using new android storyboard to create an application. The flow need to be like following:

> SplashFragment -> Fragment1 -> Fragment2

Following is the storyboard(`navigation_main.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/launch_navigation_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/splashFragment" android:name="com.myapp.android.SplashFragment"
              android:label="fragment_splash" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_fragment1"
                app:destination="@id/fragment1"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1"
              android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment1"
              android:label="fragment1" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register_msisdn">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
                app:destination="@id/fragment2" app:popUpTo="@+id/fragment1"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim" app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment2"
              android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment2"
              android:label="fragment_fragment2" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment2"/>
</navigation>
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="MainActivity">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mainNavigationHostFragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_main" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

App Theme is withou t action bar since I don't want the actionbar to show up:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Basically I need a `Fragment1` to `Fragment2` navigation and then on hardware back button press, back to `Fragment1`. To navigate from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2`, I have the following code in Fragment1:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2)
```

`SplashFragment` should not be maintained in the stack, since it is not required after first time showing in launch. That is why I have `popTo` only in `Fragment1` to `Fragment2` action. But after running the same, pressing back from `Fragment2`, for the first time does nothing(doesn't pop) and the second time, it crashes with the following exception:

```
2019-04-25 16:52:43.841 28598-28598/com.selfcare.safaricom E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
2019-04-25 16:52:43.842 28598-28598/com.selfcare.safaricom E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-04-25 16:52:43.846 28598-28598/com.selfcare.safaricom E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.selfcare.safaricom:id/action_splashFragment_to_registerMSISDNFragment is unknown to this NavController
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:803)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:744)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:718)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.handleLaunchStatus(SplashFragment.kt:51)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.access$handleLaunchStatus(SplashFragment.kt:16)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment$attachLaunchObserver$1.onChanged(SplashFragment.kt:44)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment$attachLaunchObserver$1.onChanged(SplashFragment.kt:16)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:424)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:376)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:185)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.attachLaunchObserver(SplashFragment.kt:43)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.onViewCreated(SplashFragment.kt:35)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:895)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2092)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1822)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:298)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:288)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$1.handleOnBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:144)
        at androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed(OnBackPressedDispatcher.java:136)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onBackPressed(ComponentActivity.java:283)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3083)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2716)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3366)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:80)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:98)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2736)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:342)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(Vie
2019-04-25 16:52:43.849 28598-28598/com.selfcare.safaricom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.selfcare.safaricom, PID: 28598
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.selfcare.safaricom:id/action_splashFragment_to_registerMSISDNFragment is unknown to this NavController
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:803)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:744)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:718)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.handleLaunchStatus(SplashFragment.kt:51)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.access$handleLaunchStatus(SplashFragment.kt:16)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment$attachLaunchObserver$1.onChanged(SplashFragment.kt:44)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment$attachLaunchObserver$1.onChanged(SplashFragment.kt:16)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:424)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:376)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:185)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.attachLaunchObserver(SplashFragment.kt:43)
        at com.myapp.android.SplashFragment.onViewCreated(SplashFragment.kt:35)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:895)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2092)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1822)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:298)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:288)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$1.handleOnBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:144)
        at androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed(OnBackPressedDispatcher.java:136)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onBackPressed(ComponentActivity.java:283)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3083)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2716)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3366)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:80)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:98)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2736)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:342)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
2019-04-25 16:52:43.851 28598-28598/com.selfcare.safaricom E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4453)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4779)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2571)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:2081)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:2072)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2548)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

`SplashFragment` line 51 is:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_fragment1)
```

This exception is gone if I remove the popTo from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2` action, but then also the back button doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1:**

As per Stavro Xhardha's comment, I made some modification to the navigation XML:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/splashFragment" android:name="com.myapp.android.SplashFragment"
          android:label="fragment_splash" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_fragment1"
            app:destination="@id/fragment1"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true" app:popUpTo="@+id/splashFragment"/> <!--Added this line -->
</fragment>
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1"
          android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment1"
          android:label="fragment1" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register_msisdn">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/fragment2" app:popUpTo="@+id/fragment1"/>
</fragment>
<fragment android:id="@+id/fragment2"
          android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment2"
          android:label="fragment_fragment2" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment2"/>
```

And in `MainActivity` override onBackPressed as follows:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    if (!findNavController(R.id.launchNavigationHostFragment).navigateUp()) {
        finish()
    }
}
```

Now `Fragment2` pops to `Fragment1`, but subsequent back press on `Fragment1` keeps on bringing `Fragment1` in a loop. I am not able to exit the app.

Comment: well I don't really know the answer but possibly I can help you with this link 
https://proandroiddev.com/android-navigation-component-tips-tricks-implementing-splash-screen-f0f5ce046a09

Comment: That doesn't work either. The back navigation still not working. The crash went away after including the pop action in splash though. But Fragment2 not still poping to Fragment1

Comment: have you overriden the `OnSupportNavigateUp()` on your activity ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not being called.

Comment: Ok, your first comment actually works with a small modification inactivity code, but there is still one issue. I will update the question.

Comment: drop the `super.onBackPressed()` please and than replace `finish()` with `super.onBackPressed()`

Comment: ok , if you have overriden the `onSupportNavigateUp()` please remove it , might have misguided you . happened to me once too

Comment: Doesn't help either

Comment: can you show what dependencies you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out the issue and solved it.

The issue was that, I was observing a `MutableLiveData` from `ViewModel` and based on its value the navigation was happening. But I was not aware that the life cycle owner of fragment tends to destroy the Observer and reinstantiate it based on view life cycle to avoid leaks. Hence once the navigation happens, the Observer is no longer there and the code to navigate is within the observer. The same code is required on navigating back, hence when trying to access it, the code crashes.

I solved the issue by using an interface to give callback to fragment when the navigation needs to be done.

Comment: Yes! you are correct if we are navigating inside live data callback is usually happens

Comment: What does your solution look like

Comment: It is a simple interface callback. Fragment acts as a listener to ViewModel using an interface. When the interface method is called from ViewModel, it is inviked in fragment, and the navigation happends there.

Answer (score 0):

Your error log is saying that you are calling an action with navcontroller with action id action_splashFragment_to_registerMSISDNFragment. Try to find that action id and check if it is valid or not. Also use `app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment" app:popUpToInclusive="true"` in  `action_splashFragment_to_fragment1` instead of `action_fragment1_to_fragment2`. This will remove splash fragment from the backstack. Here is the code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/launch_navigation_graph"
                app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

        <fragment android:id="@+id/splashFragment" android:name="com.myapp.android.SplashFragment"
                  android:label="fragment_splash" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_fragment1"
                    app:destination="@id/fragment1"
                app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                  android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment1"
                  android:label="fragment1" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register_msisdn">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
                    app:destination="@id/fragment2"
                    app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim" app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"/>
        </fragment>
        <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                  android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment2"
                  android:label="fragment_fragment2" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment2"/>
    </navigation>
```

Comment: That was helpul after implementing onBackPressed, but I am still stuck with an issue mentioned under Edit1

Comment: You don't need to override onBackPressed. Also try removing app:popUpTo="@+id/fragment1" from action action_fragment1_to_fragment2.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the observer after navigating to a new fragment.Like this:

`myLiveData.removeObservers(this)`