# DataBindingUtil plus NavHostFragment back navigation not working

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

[**I had posted a question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55848234/android-navcontroller-hardware-back-button-crash) earlier regarding NavHostFragment not working on back press. The question was not answered by anyone, hence putting a couple of days effort into it, I finally managed to figure out the issue.(I am only adding new code missing in the earlier question and changed code here, to reduce question length)

The navigation graph is changed to following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/launch_navigation_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/splashFragment" android:name="com.myapp.android.SplashFragment"
              android:label="fragment_splash" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_fragment1"
                app:destination="@id/fragment1"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/splashFragment"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment1"
              android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment1"
              android:label="fragment1" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register_msisdn">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2"
                app:destination="@id/fragment2" app:popUpTo="@+id/fragment1"
                app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment2"
              android:name="com.myapp.android.Fragment2"
              android:label="fragment_fragment2" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment2"/>
</navigation>
```

Some information which was missing from the previous question. The fragment binding was earlier done like this(Code below is for Fragment1, same is done in Fragment2):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: Fragment1Binding =
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity!!, R.layout.fragment1)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    val fragment1ViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Fragment1ViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = fragment1ViewModel
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)
}
```

The above code, with the navigation graph, now doesn't crash, but the back button simply refuse to work. It doesn't pop fragment, just exit on second back press.

Now I figured out that inflating the UI using `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` was the reason why my code was not working. I figured it out by creating another sample project step by step until I figured out when it stops working. I made the sample project work using data binding by using DataBindingUtil to bind to view inflated in OnCreateView like following. I remove the oncreate override.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false)
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.bind<Fragment1Binding>(rootView)
    binding?.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    val fragment1ViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(Fragment1ViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = fragment1ViewModel
    return rootView
}
```

Now, this code works in the sample project, but when I place the same on my final project(In sample project I simply place buttons and click to navigate where as in my original project I have webservice calls and view model observing for navigating), the above code crashes with following exception when pressing back from Fragment2(similar crash in Fragment1 back press as well if I press back from Fragment1).

```
2019-04-30 14:00:47.043 18087-18087/com.selfcare.safaricom E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
2019-04-30 14:00:47.043 18087-18087/com.selfcare.safaricom E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
2019-04-30 14:00:47.047 18087-18087/com.selfcare.safaricom E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.selfcare.safaricom:id/action_fragment1_to_fragment2 is unknown to this NavController
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:803)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:744)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:718)
        at com.myapp.android.Fragment2.handleLaunchStatus(Fragment2.kt:53)
        at com.myapp.android.Fragment2.access$handleLaunchStatus(Fragment2.kt:18)
        at com.myapp.android.Fragment2$attachLaunchObserver$1.onChanged(Fragment2.kt:46)
        at com.myapp.android.Fragment2$attachLaunchObserver$1.onChanged(Fragment2.kt:18)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:424)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:376)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:185)
        at com.myapp.android.Fragment2.attachLaunchObserver(Fragment2.kt:45)
        at com.myapp.android.Fragment2.onViewCreated(Fragment2.kt:37)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:895)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2092)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1866)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1822)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:298)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:288)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:241)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$1.handleOnBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:144)
        at androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed(OnBackPressedDispatcher.java:136)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onBackPressed(ComponentActivity.java:283)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3083)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2716)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3366)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:80)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:98)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:558)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2736)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:342)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5037)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4905)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4426)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4479)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4445)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4585)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(Vie
```

I googled with the exception but found nothing useful in this particular context that can solve my issue. Please help.